# Proving an inequality involving absolute values and radicals

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, roots, radicals

I am trying to understand the proof of a bound for the roots of a polynomial by Kojima, which is roughly sketched by Howard Bell in https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313703?origin=crossref.
The proof involves using the companion matrix of a polynomial $f(x)=a_n x^n + \cdots + a_0$ and applying Gershgorins cicle theorem to the columns of the matrix.

The theorem by Kojima states that for positive numbers $\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n$ with $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n = 1$ the zeros of $f(x)$ satisfy
$$
|x|\leq \max\left(\left|
\frac{1}{\lambda_j}\frac{a_{n-j}}{a_n}
\right|^{\frac{1}{j}}
\right).
$$

My problem lies in proving the inequality
$$
\left| \frac{a_0}{a_n \rho^{n-1}} \right| + 
\left| \frac{a_1}{a_n \rho^{n-2}} \right| + 
\cdots +
\left| \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n} \right| 
\leq
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_n)\rho =
\rho,
$$
where we chose $\rho$ to be
$$
\rho =
\max\left(\left|
\frac{1}{\lambda_j}\frac{a_{n-j}}{a_n}
\right|^{\frac{1}{j}}
\right),
\quad
j=1,\cdots,n.
$$
I have tried using induction starting with a polynomial of degree $n = 1$ but it got really messy and led me nowhere, since I'm not entirely sure how to work with the $\max$ expression in the induction step. Is there another, maybe simpler way?

Any advice on how to prove this inequality would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Start with $\forall j: \left|
\frac{1}{\lambda_j}\frac{a_{n-j}}{a_n}
\right|^{\frac{1}{j}} \le \rho$ ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't understand how this relates to the left side of the inequality.
If I could show that $$\forall j: \left| \frac{a_{j-1}}{a_n \rho^{n-j}} \right| \leq \lambda_j \rho,$$ the claim would follow, but I am missing a few steps. I think taking the $j$-th root in the $\max$ term and dividing the terms of the sum by $\rho^{n-j}$ might cancel each other out, but I don't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $j=1, \ldots, n$ is
$$
\left| \frac{1}{\lambda_j}\frac{a_{n-j}}{a_n} \right|^{\frac{1}{j}} \le \rho 
\implies \left| \frac{a_{n-j}}{a_n} \right| \le \lambda_j\rho^j 
\implies \left| \frac{a_{n-j}}{a_n \rho^{j-1}} \right| \le \lambda_j\rho 
$$
and adding these estimates gives the desired
$$
\left| \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n \rho^{0}} \right| + 
\left| \frac{a_{n-2}}{a_n \rho^{1}} \right| + 
\cdots +
\left| \frac{a_{0}}{a_n \rho^{n-1}} \right| 
\leq
(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots+\lambda_n)\rho \, .
$$